# How to deploy new autoscaled ECS service with high initial load? Instances fail the health check and get removed before autoscaling kicks in

Tags: amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I want to deploy a new autoscaled ECS service that will receive a high initial load immediately.

While the autoscaling policy is quite wide (scales from a minimum of 1 instance to 20, as traffic, varies a lot during the day), I am running into the problem that the initial load on the containers is so much that it results in all of them failing to pass the health checks and the system removing the containers *before* scaling them up.

What's the recommended way of dealing with this? Right now I'm simply trying to increase the minimum number of instances, but this will result in many unnecessary instances in the morning when the load is low.

Comment: Try to deploy it in 2 steps:1. minimum instances: 20, then step 2 where minimum will be 1 and you let autoscaling to scale down based on current load

Comment: That seems like a naive way that would probably work, but is this really the best solution to a problem that many applications face? I was originally expecting AWS to have some sort of "initialLoadCapacity", but I haven't found it.

Comment: I don't think "many applications" face the scenario where the moment they are deployed they already have a huge amount of traffic trying to hit them. It's sort of a strange scenario you have. If you are deploying a brand new service that didn't exist before, and it is getting tons of traffic the instant it is deployed, then it absolutely makes sense to set the initial desired task count to a higher number than `1`.

Comment: Wouldn't update the service in the near future result in the same problem? Or is ECS smart enough to perform some kind of rolling update?

Comment: Update of running ECS service will respect current desired task count, so update is not an issue. Only a creating of the new service in your case.

Comment: Can confirm this solution works!